# Half of line stroke is hidden on the SVG edge

Tags: svg

If SVG line touches SVG edge, half of the line stroke will be outside of SVG and will be hidden (see example of line chart below, last tick at the right has half-width tickness).

[image]

What are the techincs to avoid it? Is there a way to scale out SVG a little bit, so the SVG image will be smaller and don't touch SVG borders? Something like adding padding?

I'm using non-fixed aspect ratio as `height:1rem` and `width:100%`, as it's supposed to take all the place available.

The viewbox scaling doesn't work

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
.chart {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <svg height="1rem" width="100%" class="text-left" viewBox="-5% 0 105% 1rem">
    <line x1="25%" y1="5%" x2="25%" y2="25%" stroke="#6B7280" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="50%" y1="5%" x2="50%" y2="25%" stroke="#6B7280" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="100%" y1="5%" x2="100%" y2="25%" stroke="#6B7280" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="15.138888888888888%" height="50%" fill="#111827"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: add a viewBox so everything is visible.

Comment: svg height="100px" width="100px" viewBox="-5 -5 110 110"

Comment: Since for the first line x1 = x2 = 0 half stroke will be drawn outside the svg canvas. To understand what is happening add svg{overflow:visible}

Comment: @MichaelMullany please see the updated example, for some reason viewbox doesn't work

Comment: @enxaneta yes, setting overflow:visible and adding margin to SVG fixes the issue.

Comment: in the updated example you have now an invalid viewBox attribute. Use only numbers.

Comment: Setting `overflow: visible` is not really a fix.  It is a workaround.  The real problem is your SVG. The better solution is to fix your SVG.

Comment: viewBox units specify where the origin of the viewBox is and how many "userSpaceOnUse units" (the SVG distance units) are in the width and height of the viewBox respectively. viewBox does not take CSS dimensions (like px, REM, % etc.) There are many good articles written on how the SVG viewBox works - here is one: https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: Actually @AlexCraft, I take it back.  In your case, `overflow: visible` might actually be the best solution.  Using a `viewBox` will cause scaling problems.  Which people will likely then suggest you fix by adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. Which will then result in your graph ticks being stretched wider than 2px.  So long story short: as long as you are just overflowing by a pixel or so, `overflow: visible` is probably the simples and best approach.